# Is it possible to upload multiple images for AWS Rekognition without using s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I am trying to implement AWS Rekognition. Be default API allows only one image.
I want to upload multiple image for face recognition. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

**No** , it is simply not possible. You can only provide a single image as an input to rekognition API's. The only possible way to use rekognition with multiple images is to iterate over each image and call API for each image.